# SSH vs/and Password

Tags: ssh, login, password, root, keys

I have a VPS that I am logging to `root` via SSH keys.

Now, I created another user `user1` with the command `adduser` and I assigned a password to it. However, whenever I try to login to the server via `winSCP` using `user1` I still get the error that I need to enter the private key and can't login using the password for user 1.

My questions are as follows:

- Can a user have the possibility to login via the 2 methods? That is, using the SSH keys and a password?
- If SSH is used, are all the users of the system bound to use the keys to login?

Comment: You can add rules on per-user basis in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, however to give the second user another SSH key and add it accordingly is the safer way to go. Allowing password usage with ssh is somewhat dangerous as it opens the VPS to brute force attempts on said account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add rules for that particular user on the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file like the example at the end of this answer. But before **be warned, allowing password login via SSH is somewhat unsafe** in terms of brute-force attempts possible to the server. So the safest way to go is to create another SSH key on the VPS or another Linux machine with the following line. best is to switch to user1 on that machine before you start using the following commands with `su - user1`. (Note: you should change into the directory where you want the key-pair to be created as the `-f` has a hard time with paths):

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "user1_email@example.com" -f user1_key
```

The user can change the passphrase himself later by copying his key-pair for a short time onto the VPS or on another Linux machine with:

```bash
ssh-keygen -p -f user1_key
```

Then give the private key (`user1_key`) to user1 and place the public key (`user1_key.pub`) in the users home directory under `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the VPS then change ownership to user1 or you do `su - user1` before doing that to prevent undesired wrong ownership inside the home directory of user1.

```bash
mkdir -p /home/user1/.ssh
cat user1_key.pub >> /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys
# The next line is only needed if you have done the two above as 'root'
chown -Rv user1:user1 /home/user1/.ssh
```

The key-pair creation process can be done on Windows too using WinScp, see [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen) for reference. You might then want to make sure the public and the private key have the right permissions set, which is `0600` for the users private key and `0644` for the users public key. (Note: copying the key to a windows formatted USB stick or drive lets the key loose its set permissions, so you want to double check on that.

If you however really want to make this user able to log in via password, you can change the following line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```bash
AllowUsers mainuser user1
```

And add the following at the end:

For enabling password only:

```bash
Match User user1
    PubkeyAuthentication no
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

For enabling both:

```bash
Match User user1
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

For enabling ssh only you can remove that part or set it to:

```bash
Match User user1
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

More reading material which might not necessarily related to the question but to SSH in general you can find [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server), just be aware that some information is specified for digital-ocean but still useful. See as well the [manpage for the `ssh-keygen` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ssh-keygen) and the [manpage for the `ssh` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ssh).

<sub>Thanks to [@Eliah-Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) for proofreading and suggesting corrections and additions.</sub>